# Android Studio Java converting values app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

I am trying to make a small application which takes the input of an edittext and converts the given unit to another unit for example degrees to gon.

I have a problem because when I enter a value and then click the "convert" button, my app keeps crashing.

Any help what could cause the crash?

Main activity:

```
package com.example.winkelmammadov;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static EditText et_Grad, et_Rad, et_Gon;
Button btn_reset, btn_umrechnen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupUI();
    reset();
    buttonrechnen();
}


public void setupUI() {
    et_Grad = findViewById(R.id.et_Grad);
    et_Rad = findViewById(R.id.et_Rad);
    et_Gon = findViewById(R.id.et_Gon);
    btn_reset = findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);
    btn_umrechnen = findViewById(R.id.btn_umrechnen);
}

public void reset() {
    btn_reset.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et_Grad.setText("");
            et_Rad.setText("");
            et_Gon.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public void buttonrechnen() {
    btn_umrechnen.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Winkel.umrechnen();
        }
    });
}


}
```

and my convert class:

```
package com.example.winkelmammadov;

public class Winkel extends MainActivity {

public static void umrechnen() {

        String gon = et_Gon.getText().toString();
        String grad = et_Grad.getText().toString();
        String rad = et_Grad.getText().toString();

        et_Gon.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(grad) * 200 / 180));
        et_Gon.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(rad) * 200 / Math.PI));

        et_Rad.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(gon) * Math.PI / 200));
        et_Rad.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(grad) * Math.PI / 180));

        et_Grad.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(gon) * 180 / 200));
        et_Grad.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(rad) * 180 / Math.PI));

    }
  }
```

EDIT: DEBUGGEER LOG

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.winkelmammadov, PID: 11266
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at 
sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at com.example.winkelmammadov.Winkel.umrechnen(Winkel.java:26)
    at 
com.example.winkelmammadov.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
  Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 
  'socket'
```

Comment: Post stacktrace, so we can see error

Comment: Error logs pls..

Comment: I put in the error log from debugger if thats what u wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextUtils.isEmpty(String s)` in order to check if `gon`, `grad` or `rad` has some value in it befor trying to parse it to `Double`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your field before parse double:

```
private void someMethod(String str) {
   double AText = ParseDouble(angleAField.getText());
   double BText = ParseDouble(angleBField.getText());
   
   // other code here same
}

double validateParsing(String strNumber) {
 if (strNumber != null && strNumber.length() > 0) {
   try {
      return Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
   } catch(Exception e) {
      return -1;   // or some value to mark this field is wrong. or make a function validates field first ...
    }
}
 else return 0;
}
```

Or simply you can use: `TextUtils.isEmpty(String s)` which returns true if the string is null or 0-length.